# Execute a script without a console window without using pythonw.exe

Tags: python, httpserver, pythonw

I have a python script that uses the `http.server` module that I would like to run without a terminal window being shown. Unfortunately, due to how I'm doing this, running the script in `pythonw.exe` does not work.

Here is the script:

```
import os
from http.server import CGIHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories = ['/scripts']
server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 1271), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Unfortunately, I don't know any way get any error logs because, y'know, *pythonw doesn't show the console*. If anyone can tell me how to get the error logs, I'll be happy to add them to the bottom of this post.

I'm running 64-bit Windows 10 and python 3.6.6, if that makes a difference.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I—for the life of me—cannot find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried running it using the normal python.exe first?

Comment: I have, but I'd like it to *not* display a window. It works fine in python.exe, but not pythonw.exe

Comment: Redirect stderr? eg: `pythonw some_file.py 2>errors.txt` ?

Comment: I tried that before posting. It didn't write to the file, presumably because the program never "naturally" ends. Though I guess if I hit CTRL+C it would write to the file. I'll get back to you on whether that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just store output to a text file like this:

```
from http.server import CGIHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import sys

handler = CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories = ['/scripts']
server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 1271), handler)
sys.stderr = open('log.txt', 'w', 1)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that before and it didn't work. It worked this time though. Thank you!